# Problem with Template in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, templates, xaml

I have a Silverlight application that I am trying to style. This style simply fades in a different color border when the control gains focus. When the control does not have focus, I want it to return to its original look. My style currently has two problems:

1. When a user clicks in the TextBox, a 1px border seems to be added to the right edge if the mouse cursor is over it. But, if I move the mouse cursor out while the control has focus, a gap appears only in the right edge.
2. My transition does not seem to fade from the focussed state to the non-selected state.

Can someone please look at my template and help me identify what I'm doing wrong? I have included my code where and you should be able to just copy and paste it.

```
<sdk:Page   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"   xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" xmlns:ee="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/effects"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="InputFocusBlur.Input"
    Title="Input Page"
    d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">

  <sdk:Page.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationToolTipTemplate">
      <Grid x:Name="Root" Margin="5,0" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
          <TranslateTransform x:Name="xform" X="-25"/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OpenStates">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
              <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
              <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="Open">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="xform">
                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                      <BackEase Amplitude=".3" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                  </DoubleAnimation>
                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Open">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="xform"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
          </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Border Background="#052A2E31" CornerRadius="5" Margin="4,4,-4,-4"/>
        <Border Background="#152A2E31" CornerRadius="4" Margin="3,3,-3,-3"/>
        <Border Background="#252A2E31" CornerRadius="3" Margin="2,2,-2,-2"/>
        <Border Background="#352A2E31" CornerRadius="2" Margin="1,1,-1,-1"/>
        <Border Background="#FFDC000C" CornerRadius="2"/>
        <Border CornerRadius="2">
          <TextBlock Foreground="White" MaxWidth="250" Margin="8,4,8,4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" UseLayoutRounding="false"/>
        </Border>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="myField" TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
            <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
              <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                  <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.7" To="MouseOver">
                      <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager.TransitionEffect>
                        <ee:FadeTransitionEffect/>
                      </ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager.TransitionEffect>
                    </VisualTransition>
                  </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                  <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF11DA0B" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverBorder"/>
                      <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF11DA0B" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                      <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF11DA0B" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                      <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF11DA0B" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <Thickness>1</Thickness>
                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF11DA0B" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadOnlyVisualElement"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                  <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.7" To="Unfocused">
                      <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager.TransitionEffect>
                        <ee:FadeTransitionEffect/>
                      </ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager.TransitionEffect>
                    </VisualTransition>
                  </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement"/>
                      <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF11DA0B" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                      <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF11DA0B" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <Thickness>1</Thickness>
                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                  <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
              </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
                <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
              </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
              <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="1" Opacity="1" Margin="1,0,-1,0" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Grid>
                  <Border x:Name="ReadOnlyVisualElement" Background="#5EC9C9C9" Opacity="0"/>
                  <Border x:Name="MouseOverBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                  </Border>
                </Grid>
              </Border>
              <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" BorderBrush="#A5F7F7F7" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#A5F7F7F7" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
              <Border x:Name="FocusVisualElement" BorderBrush="#FF6DBDD1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="1" Opacity="0"/>
              <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                  <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}">
                    <ToolTip.Triggers>
                      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                          <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                  <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                              </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                          </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                      </EventTrigger>
                    </ToolTip.Triggers>
                  </ToolTip>
                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="12" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12">
                  <Path Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="#FFDC000C" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                  <Path Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#ffffff" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                </Grid>
              </Border>
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </sdk:Page.Resources>

  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" >
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="48,194,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="270" Style="{StaticResource myField}"/>
  </Grid>
</sdk:Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your myfield style.  First and foremost, you are changing the same properties in Visual States that are in separate VisualStateGroups.  This can lead to erratic behavior (Blend shows this warning if you open up your template).

Secondly, you are controlling the border colors of the focused element, plus the main border.  Just pick one and go with it.

Try this style instead with these issues fixed.  I think it's what you're looking for:

```
<Style x:Key="myField"
           TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="#FF000000" />
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9"
                                  Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9"
                                  Offset="0.375" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597"
                                  Offset="0.375" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584"
                                  Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">

                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.7"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">                                        
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverBorder" d:IsOptimized="True"/>

                                    </Storyboard>                                        
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                            To="1"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                            To="1"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ReadOnlyVisualElement" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.7"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                            To="1"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
                                    <Storyboard/>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
                            <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager />
                        </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                CornerRadius="1"
                                Opacity="1"
                                BorderBrush="Black"
                                BorderThickness="1">
                            <Grid>
                                <Border x:Name="ReadOnlyVisualElement"
                                        Background="#5EC9C9C9"
                                        Opacity="0" />
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                                                  BorderThickness="0"
                                                  IsTabStop="False"
                                                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement"
                                BorderBrush="#A5F7F7F7"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Background="#A5F7F7F7"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                Opacity="0" />
                        <Border x:Name="FocusVisualElement"
                                BorderBrush="#FF11DA0B"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                Margin="0"
                                Opacity="0"
                                BorderThickness="2" />
                        <Border x:Name="MouseOverBorder"
                                BorderBrush="#FF11DA0B"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                Margin="0"
                                Opacity="0" 
                                BorderThickness="2"/>
                        <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement"
                                BorderBrush="#FFDB000C"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                CornerRadius="1"
                                Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip"
                                         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                         Placement="Right"
                                         PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                         Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}">
                                    <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible"
                                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </ToolTip.Triggers>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <Grid Background="Transparent"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                  Height="12"
                                  Margin="1,-4,-4,0"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                  Width="12">
                                <Path Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z"
                                      Fill="#FFDC000C"
                                      Margin="1,3,0,0" />
                                <Path Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8"
                                      Fill="#ffffff"
                                      Margin="1,3,0,0" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. However, my challenge is, when the control has a mouse over it, or has focus, I want the border to be 2px in size. But then, when the control is in a normal state or loses focus, I want it to go back to having a 1px border. This is what seems to be causing the problem.  Thank you for trying!

Comment: I just edited the code and re-posted to include the mouse-over change as well as a change to a border thickness of 2

Comment: Oh my word! Thank you so much for your help. For the life of me I couldn't get it to do this. You're the man (or woman)!